# Django User Permissions

Tags: django, django-views

I have a django app in which only superuser or staff members can create an object. Here's how I did it,

model,

```
class Data(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
```

view,

```
def data_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    else:
        # Create the Data object . . .
```

After doing so I created 2 users, first one is superuser (`admin`) & second one is a normal user (`test`). After that, I logged in as superuser (`admin`) into django admin panel & changed second user's (`test`) permission to staff & also gave him permission to create the `data` object.

But Problem is that it's still returning `Http404` error whenever I try to create `data` object as (`test`) second user. Why is it happening?

Also: When I changed second user's (`test`) permission to `superuser` instead of `staff`, everything worked fine it was able to create `data` object (no longer 404 error). But I wants to keep it `staff` & be able to create the data.

Comment: Whats the output of `request.user.is_staff` and  `request.user.is_superuser`  inside your view, when you logged-in as `test user` ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sir, I made `test` user a staff member from superuser account in the admin panel. But as the staff member `test` user is not able to create the data.

Comment: Just do a `print()` just after the function creation

Comment: just like this , `def data_create(request):
    print(request.user.is_staff)
    print(request.user.is_superuser)
    return "somethind"`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sir, I did it directly in template `{{ request.user.is_staff }}` is returning `True` & `{{ request.user.is_superuser }}` is returning `False`, when I'm logged in as `test` user.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Also, I did it for superuser `admin`, & in admin's case both are returning `True`!

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sir, i just reversed the code to, `if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:`
        # Create the Data object . . .
    `else:`
        raise Http404. Everything is working fine now ,but I'm confused why is it happening?, I mean the new code is still doing the same thing as previously then why different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `if` condition, so, change it as below

```
def data_create(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        # Create the Data Object
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**Why the behaviour?**

```
In [11]: not False or not True
Out[11]: True
```

Hopes the above statement describes the nature.

Comment: It's confusing, isn't the code still same? I mean just conditions are reversed then why is it behaving differently?

Comment: No, it's not. `not False or not True` is equal to `True or False` which is equal to `True`

Comment: Now I get it. Thank You very much Sir :)

Comment: Your if statement (the initial one) is similar to **raise 404 error if user is `not a staff` or user is `not a super user`** . In `test` user, he is only a `staff`, that is he's not a `super user`. So the condition goes wrong